# Not all orders are creating customers

Tags: magento-1.9

when our sales team creates a manual order from magento back-end you can later search for the client under "customer" drop down. However, if an order is placed through our website, you can search for the actual order, but not by the customer.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If "guest orders" are turned on, a customer can place an order without actually creating an account.

Check out http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#order-processing/checkout-guest.html